# Fast way to put boundaries of integration on the 3-dimensional integral

Tags: integration

> Calculate the triple integral
> $$
> \iiint_{G}(x+z) \,d x d y d z, \text { domain } G\text { is bounded by planes }\\ x+y=1, x-y=1
> ,x+z=1, z=0, x=0
> $$

My question is, what is the easiest and most efficient way to put boundaries on such integral? For integral, that I provided, I built a 3D representation, but from it it very difficult to understand, how $x,y,z$ are changed. And especially it hard to do with only 2D representation.

Comment: Please show the own attempts to solve the issue. Asking for the easiest way to do something may lead to the conclusion that you have a not so easy way, well, then describe it! Always show the own attempts to solve the problem, and the point where things become messy and need help. (Very often, we do not need the representation of the domain *explicitly*. Do we want to calculate the triple integral, or to understand $G$?)

Comment: @dan_fulea Basically, I need to calculate the triple integral, but to do this I need to understand $G$. My attemp was just to build those planes in 3D, which I succesfully performed here: https://www.geogebra.org/calculator

Comment: As long as you have a rough visualization of the domain, you should be able to use the given equations to get the limits.

Comment: @MathLover But on some exam I will not be able to use some software, that's why I'm asking for help

Comment: But you can do $2D$ rough sketch in different planes. It is important to understand the order of integral - some may be easier than other.

Answer (score 1):

If you visualize the domain and also from the equations of planes that $x-y=1, x+ y = 1, x+z = 1$, they all meet at point $(1,0,0)$.Using given equations to find the limits,

First for the limit of $z$, note that $z \geq 0$ and $z \leq 1-x$

Limits of $y$ is between $-(1-x) \leq y \leq (1-x)$

$0 \leq x \leq 1$

The integral is

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \int_{-(1-x)}^{1-x}\int_0^{1-x} (x+z) \ dz \ dy \ dx$

Answer (score 1):

In an exam, we need minimal visualization of the domain. I would immediately try to apply Fubini, so the question is how to "split the space" in a simplest way.

Observe that some equations are involving only $x,y$, so we will consider them first:
$$
x+y =1\ ,\ x-y=1\ ,\ x=0\ .
$$
They are delimiting in the $xOy$-plane a (solid) triangle $\Delta$ with vertices $(0,1)$, $(0,-1)$, and $(1,1)$. So $G$ contains only points $(x,y,z)$ with $(x,y)$ in $\Delta$. Now we also consider the delimiting planes "in $z$". One of them is $z=0$, so we either take points in the half-space $z\ge 0$, or points in the half-space $z\le 0$. To see further, consider also the plane $x+z=1$. It passes through points $(0,y,1)$ (and $(1,y,0)$), so we are in the "upper" half-space $z\ge 0$.

So it remains to integrate.

For each $(x,y)\in\Delta$, the possible values of $z$ are those between $z=0$ and $z=(1-x)$, so we integrate on the segment $[0,1-x]$. The integral $J$ to be computed is thus:
$$
\begin{aligned}
J 
&=
\iiint_G(x+z)\; dx\; dy\; dz\\
&=
\iint_{(x,y)\in\Delta}\; dx\; dy\int_{[0,1-x]}(x+z)\; dz\\
&=
\iint_\Delta\; dx\; dy\;\left[xz+\frac 12z^2\right]_{[0,1-x]}\\
&=
\iint_\Delta\; dx\; dy\;\cdot\; \left(x(1-x)+\frac 12(1-x)^2\right)\\
&=
\int_{x\in[0,1]}dx\;\cdot\; \left(x(1-x)+\frac 12(1-x)^2\right)
\int_{y\in[-(1-x),\ (1-x)]}\; dy
\\
&=
\int_{x\in[0,1]}dx\;\cdot\; \left(x(1-x)+\frac 12(1-x)^2\right)
\cdot 2(1-x)
\\
&=
\int_{x\in[0,1]}dx\;\cdot\; \left((1-x)x+\frac 12x^2\right)
\cdot 2x
\\
&=
\int_0^1(2x^2(1-x)+x^3)\; dx
=
\int_0^1(2x^2-x^3)\; dx
\\
&=\frac 23-\frac 14=\frac 1{12}(8-3)=\frac 5{12}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

---

We can alternatively compute the integral,
after we visualize it as the pyramid with vertex $(1,0,0)\in Ox$ and with basis the rectangle with vertices  in the $yOz$-plane $(0,1,1)$, $(0,-1,1)$, $(0,1,0)$, $(0,-1,0)$.
So it is $\{0\}\times[-1,1]\times[0,1]$.

We let $x$ run from $0$ to $1$, then the corresponding $x$-section in $G$ is the rectangle $G_x=\{x\}\times[-1+x,1-x]\times[0,1-x]$. So

$$
\begin{aligned}
J 
&=
\iiint_G(x+z)\; dx\; dy\; dz\\
&=
\int_{x\in[0,1]}dx\int_{y\in[-(1-x),\ (1+x)]}dy\int_{z\in[0,1-x]}(x+z)\; dz\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
This is the same, but maybe the visualization is simpler.